# perl cpanm installation make problem

Tags: perl, installation, cpan

I'm trying to install the cpan module installer and I ran into an issue making the package.

I ran:

```
sudo cpan App::cpanminus
```

My results:

```
// lots of other successful stuff
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.43)
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state

CPAN.pm: Going to build M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.4008.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for App::cpanminus
make: *** No rule to make target `/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/config.h', needed by `Makefile'.  Stop.
MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.4008.tar.gz
make -- NOT OK
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Any idea what my issue is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [install instructions](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3a%3acpanminus) for cpan minus say to run:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
```

or, if you are wanting a local perl instead of the system perl:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

Given that the main advantage of cpan minus is that it avoids all the fuss of configuring cpan to work, using cpan to install it seems like more pain then it is worth.